# What is the name for the kind of game of jumping dinosaur from Chrome's 404 page?

Tags: terminology

Basically, I want to know the name so I can find if anyone already built a clone game with PhaserJS like the one of jumping dinosaur from Chrome's 404 page.

Comment: The title of the question and the content of the question do not match. What's your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a 2D *infinite runner*. It's a particular type of 2D side-scrolling games, the levels are generated dinamically, objects and obstacles are as well. It's the same mechanics of Jetpack Joyride and similars.